# How to create a Cordova plugin that is using LinphoneSDK functions

Tags: android, iphone, cordova-plugins, linphone-sdk

I am going to build a Cordova plugin that can connect to a sip server for both android and iOS version.

The program requires the usage of Linphone SDK.

I tried to download Linphone SDK for both android and iPhone.

First for android, I only found .jar file.

How to use it for my project.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what .jar file you found but it's probably not linphone-sdk.
It is distributed as an .aar file through [Maven](https://linphone.org/maven_repository).

You can also build it yourself, following [README](https://gitlab.linphone.org/BC/public/linphone-sdk/-/blob/master/README.md) instructions from linphone-sdk git repository.